# ReadGrib (from rNOMADS) returning empty lists

Tags: r, grib

```
urls.out <- CrawlModels(abbrev = "gfs_0p50", depth = 2)
levels <- c("2 m above ground", "800 mb")
variables <- c("TMP", "RH") #Temperature and relative humidity
grib.info <- GribGrab(urls.out[2], my.pred, levels, variables)
ReadGrib(grib.info[[1]]$file.name, variables = variables, levels = levels)
```

Why is `ReadGrib` returning empty lists? This example follows the documentation pretty closely for `ReadGrib`'s usage: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rNOMADS/rNOMADS.pdf